# Importing multiple text files using VBA Macro

Tags: excel, data-import, vba

I have a daily dump of 2 different text files (in the same folder) that get overwritten daily. I would like to be able to import them into an active spreadsheet with tab delimited, at the same time with a VBA code. I would really appreciate the help!

I am using excel 2016. My manual import method of 1 of the text file when recorded gives this code which is how i would like BOTH the text files to be imported (formatting preserved):

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\Mr D\Music\New folder\B.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "B"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers =enter code here False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

The code that i have tried using is from other similar questions posted here does not seem to work:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Mr D\Music\")

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

        ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
        Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

        ' Put data on one row in active sheet
        For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
            cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
        Next

        ' Move to next row
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What help would you like?  Your question doesn't explain what problems you are having.

Comment: If the filenames don't change from day to day, you could create data connections to them and refresh each day.

Comment: I would like the code that can execute this. You are correct i need the data connection and would want to refresh every day. I have looked through similar questions here and the vba code mentioned is not executing it accordingly.

Comment: I have been able to get rid of user defined error by activating the Windows Script Host Object Model. I can open 1 text file, but unable to load both at the same time (the second one immediately in the last empty row)

Comment: Instead of explaining your problems in the comments, [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48134634/edit) to explain what issues you are having, and to include the code that you are having the issues with.  **Then** we might have something we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

do like this if your text files is with tab delimited.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range
Dim sFolder As String, vDB, Ws As Worksheet
Dim rngT As Range
' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want

    sFolder = "C:\Users\Mr D\Music\"
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    'Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFolder & file.Name, Format:=1
        With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            vDB = .UsedRange
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Set rngT = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next file
    Ws.Range("a1").EntireRow.Delete
    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

From the second text file, the header will be ignored.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range
Dim sFolder As String, vDB, Ws As Worksheet
Dim rngT As Range
' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want

    sFolder = "C:\Users\Mr D\Music\"
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    'Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    Ws.Cells.Clear
    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        i = i + 1
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFolder & file.Name, Format:=1
        With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            If i = 1 Then
                vDB = .UsedRange
            Else
                vDB = .UsedRange.Offset(1)
            End If
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Set rngT = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next file
    Ws.Range("a1").EntireRow.Delete
    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you so much! I am assigning this macro to a button to do this and will be doing this daily as i rewrite the text files get updated daily with a new update. There is 1 more thing i would like to do and that is when the loop executes on the SECOND text file i would want the headers (titles on the first row) to be ignored and it loops from the second row. How can that be accomplished?

Comment: vDB = .UsedRange.offset (1)

Comment: Adding the above deletes it for BOTH text files. I just want it to delete for the second text file.

Comment: If i wanted to "call" this macro from a different worksheet, how would i adjust this code as this for activesheet...

Comment: @Dani,  Set Ws = ActiveSheet  to Set Ws = Sheets("sheet  name")

Comment: Will anyone demonstrate below code?

Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFolder & file.Name, Format:=1
        With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            If i = 1 Then
                vDB = .UsedRange
            Else
                vDB = .UsedRange.Offset(1)
            End If
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Set rngT = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next file
    Ws.Range("a1").EntireRow.Delete
    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing