# How To Select Entire Column Except Header/First Row In Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a selection of an entire column **except the first row**. I used the following code which i got from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1628-excel-select-column-except-header-first-row.html

```
Sub SelectColumn()
Dim xColIndex As Integer
Dim xRowIndex As Integer
xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
xRowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, xColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(2, xColIndex), Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)).Select
End Sub
```

but the RowIndex variable reads to the value 1. So the section happens from Row2 to Row1 instead of Row2 to the Last row. How can i get this corrected

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134634/importing-multiple-text-files-using-vba-macro/48135025?noredirect=1#comment83255629_48135025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to select the whole column (why?) then this. In your example you can't have any data in the relevant column.

```
Range(Cells(2, xColIndex), Cells(rows.count, xColIndex)).Select
```

Comment: My pleasure.You might want to get into the habit of accepting answers so as to engender good will.