# Importing Multiple Txt files using macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, data-import

I had previously asked this question in this post:
[Importing multiple text files using VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134634/importing-multiple-text-files-using-vba-macro)

After a while, i created an entire new workbook and when i try to copy/paste this code to a macro module, **i get a compile error: user-defined type not defined....** The code is as following:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range
Dim sFolder As String, vDB, Ws As Worksheet
Dim rngT As Range
' Get a FileSystem object
  Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want

sFolder = "C:\Users\danial.smith\Documents\Maintenance\DataDump\Reports\RawData\"
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
' set the starting point to write the data to
Set Ws = ActiveSheet
'Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFolder & file.Name, Format:=1
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        vDB = .UsedRange.Offset(1)
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Set rngT = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
Next file
Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have tried to include the Microsoft ActiveX Data Object Library as some suggest but still no luck....not sure what to do...

Comment: Pro-tip, the VBE highlights the type that is missing...

Comment: [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation) | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789611/vba-early-vs-late-binding-real-life-performance-differences | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583705/late-binding-vs-early-binding-in-vba-createobject-vs-new

Comment: Found the answer here! <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba>

Answer (score 2):

FileSystemObject requires a reference to the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** library.

Look at the references in your previous workbook.